# How to validate mulitple forms in a single formView class Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have a `formView` class as you can see below:-

**view.py**

```
class ThreadForm(FormView):
        template_name = 'thread.html'
        form_class = ThreadModelForm
        success_url = '/success'

        def form_valid(self, form):
            # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
            # It should return an HttpResponse.
            print form.cleaned_data
            return super(ThreadForm, self).form_valid(form)

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(ThreadForm, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['second_form'] = MessageModelForm
            return context
```

**thread.html**

```
{form.as_p}
{second_form.as_p}
SUBMIT
```

In my template `thread.html`, I have two modelforms but single submit button. The problem is I am not getting any data from my `second_form` and not able validate `second_form` as well. I am receiving data from `form` but not from `second_form`. Could anyone tell me how to validate `second_form` data. Thank you

One method is to use `request.post['data']` but is there any other method there?

Comment: IMHO its better to use a template view in this case. FormView is designed to handle only one form

Comment: Could you give me an example in templateview handling multiple forms?

Comment: have a look here https://github.com/utkbansal/gharonda/blob/master/properties/views.py#L87

Answer (score 5):

I do use `FormView` (or `CreateView`, `UpdateView`, etc.)
This is what I do:

```
class ThreadForm(FormView):
    template_name = 'thread.html'
    form_class = ThreadModelForm
    ...

    def get_second_form(self):
       # logic to construct second form goes here
       # if self.request.method == 'POST' you need to pass self.request.POST
       # to the form. Add whatever you need to create the form
       if self.request.method == 'POST':
          return SecondForm(self.request.POST)
       else:
          return SecondForm()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.second_form = self.get_second_form()
        if self.second_form.is_valid():
            # All good logic goes here, which in the simplest case is
            # returning super.form_valid
            return super(ThreadForm, self).form_valid(form)
        else:
            # Otherwise treat as if the first form was invalid
            return super(ThreadForm, self).form_invalid(form)

    # Do this only if you need to validate second form when first form is
    # invalid
    def form_invalid(self, form):
        self.second_form = self.get_second_form()
        self.second_form.is_valid()
        return super(ThreadForm, self).form_invalid(form)

    # Trick is here
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ThreadedForm, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['second_form'] = getattr(self, 'second_form', self.get_second_form())
        return context
```

Comment: I solved the issue by extracting data from `request.POST` but your answer is much better. I will try this, and get back to you.